# Google Classroom - Programmatically create assignment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I'm using google apps script to create assignment with an uploaded document for a classroom. However, there's an error.

> Execution failed: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name
>   "share_mode" at 'course_work.materials[0]': Cannot find field. Invalid
>   JSON payload received. Unknown name "id" at
>   'course_work.materials[0].drive_file': Cannot find field. Invalid JSON
>   payload received. Unknown name "title" at
>   'course_work.materials[0].drive_file': Cannot find field. (line 2,
>   file "TEST") [0.061 seconds total runtime]

Here's my code. I know the error is in `materials` but I'm not sure what I did wrongly.

```
function myFunction() {
  var exec = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create({
    title: "Test File",
    state: "DRAFT",
    materials: [
      {
        driveFile: {id: "1ENk55RMtApIydyPFe0uyuhmu6nSV4", title: "Test File"},
        shareMode: "STUDENT_COPY"
      }
      ],
    workType: "ASSIGNMENT"
  }, "3896298178");
  Logger.log(exec);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out the root of your issue. I've updated your codes to make it work.

Request:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ClassSource =  {
    title: "Test File",
    state: "DRAFT",
    materials: [
      {
        driveFile:{
        driveFile: {
          id: "fileID", 
          title: "Sample Document"

        },
        shareMode: "STUDENT_COPY"
        }

      }
      ],
    workType: "ASSIGNMENT"
  };

  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(ClassSource, COURSEID)
  //Logger.log(exec);
}
```

Result:

[image]

We receive `Invalid JSON payload received.` because the formating of the request is wrong. Its a little bit more complicated than I thought, that is why I tried using [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/create) to see the request format and it really helped me solve your issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Both the union and the drive resource are named 'driveFile'. Seems redundant and confusing.

Comment: @SpencerEaston I agree that its redundant and confusing. Maybe a feature request can solve this confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Per the docs `Drivefile`  property `title` is marked read only. Just use the `id`.

https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/DriveFile

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Now there's this error,
`[17-03-28 13:45:37:048 HKT] Execution failed: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "share_mode" at 'course_work.materials[0]': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "id" at 'course_work.materials[0].drive_file': Cannot find field. (line 2, file "TEST") [0.046 seconds total runtime]`

Answer (score 2):

Following ajax request can be sent to create the assignment. The code below was written for Angular but it can be easily converted to jQuery script. You can build your own courseWork object that is being passed as 'data' of ajax request to see the full Object structure visit [CourseWork API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork)

```
    $http({
        url: 'https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/'+courseId+'/courseWork?access_token='+$scope.session.access_token,
        method: 'POST',   
        data:{
            "title": title,
            "description": description,
            "state": "PUBLISHED",
            "workType": "ASSIGNMENT",
            "submissionModificationMode": "MODIFIABLE_UNTIL_TURNED_IN",
            "associatedWithDeveloper": true
        }
    }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if(response.status==200){

        }
    }, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: can this be done without Ajax - whatever that is - just vanilla Google Apps Script?