# Attaching a Drive file to an assignment with Google Classroom API

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-classroom

Using Google Apps Script I have managed to create an assignment with the following code:

```
Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create({
 "courseId": id,
 "title" : title,
 "description" : desc,
 "workType" : 'ASSIGNMENT',
 }, id)
```

This works fine, creating a draft assignment on Classroom. However, when I try to attach a Drive file like so:

```
  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create({
    "courseId": id,
    "title" : title,
    "description" : desc,
    "workType" : 'ASSIGNMENT',
    "materials" : [
      {
      "driveFile": {
        "id" : fileId,
        "title" : fileTitle,
        "alternateLink" : fileLink,
        "thumbnailUrl" : fileThumbnail,
      },
      "shareMode" : 'STUDENT_COPY',
    }
    ],
  }, id)
```

I receive these errors:

Execution failed: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "share_mode" at 'course_work.materials[0]': Cannot find field.

Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "alternate_link" at 'course_work.materials[0].drive_file': Cannot find field.

Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "id" at 'course_work.materials[0].drive_file': Cannot find field.

Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "title" at 'course_work.materials[0].drive_file': Cannot find field.

Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "thumbnail_url" at 'course_work.materials[0].drive_file': Cannot find field. (line 61, file "Classroom") [1.187 seconds total runtime]

**Any help will be appreciated, thank you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer with this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43065196/5832311). This error might happen because of wrong formatting of the request.

Sample code:

> ```
> function myFunction() {
>   var ClassSource =  {
>     title: "Test File",
>     state: "DRAFT",
>     materials: [
>       {
>         driveFile:{
>         driveFile: {
>           id: "fileID", 
>           title: "Sample Document"
>
>         },
>         shareMode: "STUDENT_COPY"
>         }
>
>       }
>       ],
>     workType: "ASSIGNMENT"
>   };
>
>   Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(ClassSource, COURSEID)
>   //Logger.log(exec);
> }
> ```

You may try this using [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/create).

Hope this helps!